# How to change text sizes based on breakpoint in Quasar?

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework

I was trying to set a custom font size and line height for each variable in quasar.variables.scss but it draws an error:

```
[plugin:vite:css] Undefined operation "(600px,) > 0".
     ╷
6831 │   $noProcNotZero: $size > 0
     │                   ^^^^^^^^^
     ╵
  node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass 6831:19  fg()
  node_modules/quasar/dist/quasar.sass 6971:3   root stylesheet
```

My style sheet is as follows:

```
// Quasar SCSS (& Sass) Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// To customize the look and feel of this app, you can override
// the Sass/SCSS variables found in Quasar's source Sass/SCSS files.

// Check documentation for full list of Quasar variables

// Your own variables (that are declared here) and Quasar's own
// ones will be available out of the box in your .vue/.scss/.sass files

// It's highly recommended to change the default colors
// to match your app's branding.
// Tip: Use the "Theme Builder" on Quasar's documentation website.

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@600&display=swap');

$primary: #da282f;
$secondary: hsl(0, 100%, 95%);
//$accent: #b927d3;
$primary-dark: #1b0000;
$background-accent: #f5f5f5;

$accent: #a0a0a0;
$background-accent: #f5f5f5;

$dark: #1d1d1d;
$dark-page: #121212;

$positive: #21ba45;
$negative: #c10015;
$info: #31ccec;
$warning: #f2c037;

$typography-font-family-secondary: 'Quicksand', sans-serif !default;

// Max width at which point
// current size ends
$breakpoint-xs: 599px !default;
$breakpoint-sm: 1023px !default;
$breakpoint-md: 1439px !default;
$breakpoint-lg: 1919px !default;

$sizes: (
  'xs': 0,
  'sm': (
    $breakpoint-xs + 1,
  ),
  'md': (
    $breakpoint-sm + 1,
  ),
  'lg': (
    $breakpoint-md + 1,
  ),
  'xl': (
    $breakpoint-lg + 1,
  ),
) !default;

$breakpoint-xs-max: (map-get($sizes, 'sm') - 0.02) !default;

$breakpoint-sm-min: map-get($sizes, 'sm') !default;
$breakpoint-sm-max: (map-get($sizes, 'md') - 0.02) !default;

$breakpoint-md-min: map-get($sizes, 'md') !default;
$breakpoint-md-max: (map-get($sizes, 'lg') - 0.02) !default;

$breakpoint-lg-min: map-get($sizes, 'lg') !default;
$breakpoint-lg-max: (map-get($sizes, 'xl') - 0.02) !default;

$breakpoint-xl-min: map-get($sizes, 'xl') !default;

//Fonts and sizes
$h1: (
  size: 5rem,
  line-height: 6rem,
  letter-spacing: -0.01562em,
  weight: 300,
) !default;
$h2: (
  size: 3.75rem,
  line-height: 3.75rem,
  letter-spacing: -0.00833em,
  weight: 300,
) !default;
$h3: (
  size: 3rem,
  line-height: 3.125rem,
  letter-spacing: normal,
  weight: 300,
) !default;
$h4: (
  size: 2.125rem,
  line-height: 2.5rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.00735em,
  weight: 400,
) !default;
$h5: (
  size: 1.5rem,
  line-height: 2rem,
  letter-spacing: normal,
  weight: 400,
) !default;
$h6: (
  size: 1.25rem,
  line-height: 2rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.0125em,
  weight: 500,
) !default;
$subtitle1: (
  size: 1rem,
  line-height: 1.75rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.00937em,
  weight: 400,
) !default;
$subtitle2: (
  size: 0.875rem,
  line-height: 1.375rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.00714em,
  weight: 500,
) !default;
$body1: (
  size: 1rem,
  line-height: 1.5rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.03125em,
  weight: 400,
) !default;
$body2: (
  size: 0.875rem,
  line-height: 1.25rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.01786em,
  weight: 400,
) !default;
$overline: (
  size: 0.75rem,
  line-height: 2rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.16667em,
  weight: 500,
) !default;
$caption: (
  size: 0.75rem,
  line-height: 1.25rem,
  letter-spacing: 0.03333em,
  weight: 400,
) !default;

@media (max-width: $breakpoint-xs-max) {
  .text-h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
  }
  .text-h2 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
  .text-h4 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
  .text-h6 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm-min) and (max-width: $breakpoint-sm-max) {
  .text-h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
  }
  .text-h2 {
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    line-height: 2.75rem;
  }
  .text-h4 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
  .text-h6 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Is breakpoint fonts not allowed to be changed this way? If so how should I approach this as I want my headers to shrink to smaller sizes as the screen shrinks.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Try changing your `$sizes` variable to:

```scss
$sizes: (
  "xs": 0,
  "sm": $breakpoint-xs + 1,
  "md": $breakpoint-sm + 1,
  "lg": $breakpoint-md + 1,
  "xl": $breakpoint-lg + 1,
);
```

The variables on the Quasar website are written in Sass and not Scss. Your code looks like it has some unnecessary parentheses.